# typescript async function not working when too much load

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise

Let say I have this module :

```
export async function beFancy () {
  let i, j, load;
  // just for trying to delay the return;
  for (i = 0; i < 999; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 999; ++j) {
      load = i + j;
    }
  }
  return 'beFancy finished';
}
```

now I make a main module for testing :

```
import {beFancy} from './mymodule';

beFancy().then((msg) => console.log(msg));
console.log('main finished');
```

If I execute, the output is as expected

```
-> main finished
-> beFancy finished
```

because `beFancy` is -asynchronous-

But now if I try to make the loop a little more intense :

```
export async function beFancy() {
  let i, j, load;
  for (i = 0; i < 9999999; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 999; ++j) {
      load = i + j;
    }
  }
  return 'beFancy finished';
}
```

and executing `main` again, the output is the same

```
-> main finished
-> beFancy finished
```

but I would expect `main finished` to display before the function `beFancy` is actually being processed. Instead the above output displays in one shot when `beFancy` finish. At first I thought the reason was because the output is only flushed at the end of the program but if I type :

```
console.log('begin');
beFancy().then((msg) => console.log(msg));
console.log('main finished');
```

"begin" displays before 'beFancy' executes, so my previous assumption is not met.

So because `beFancy` is -asynchronous- what could possibly be wrong ? Is it an unexpected behavior on my machine ?

Answer (score 1):

> So because beFancy is -asynchronous- what could possibly be wrong ?

That's because it's only `beFancy` returned value that is asynchronous. `beFancy` is mostly synchronous and blocks main thread. The code above is roughly same as:

```
  function beFancy () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let i, j, load;
      for (i = 0; i < 999; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < 999; ++j) {
          load = i + j;
        }
      }
      console.log('logged on same tick')
      resolve('logged on next tick');
    });
  }

  console.log('begin');
  beFancy().then((msg) => console.log(msg));
  console.log('main finished');
```

In order for a loop in `async` function to be asynchronous and non-blocking, it should be performed in chunks with `await`:

```
export async function beFancy () {
  let i, j, load;
  for (i = 0; i < 999; ++i) {
    await null; // next tick
    for (j = 0; j < 999; ++j) {
      load = i + j;
    }
  }
  return 'beFancy finished';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs on a single thread. It achieves performance parity (and sometimes superiority) over multi-threaded languages by taking advantage of asynchronous non-blocking I/O.

This works because most of the time, in multi-threaded languages, the application thread is sitting idle waiting for an async I/O request to return. In JavaScript, that waiting request is parked and the thread continues execution elsewhere.

This is great when you're waiting on a network call or disk, but if your async request is chewing up CPU, the thread is sitting there with it chewing away. Therefore the code you have above for all intents and purposes performs *synchronously*.

Here's the execution order of the code:

1. starts in main
2. enters beFancy method
3. sticks with the for loop in beFancy
4. returns to the caller in main with the promise
5. prints 'main finished'
6. resolves the promise
7. prints 'beFancy finished'

Replace your CPU intensive for loops with a `setTimeout( () => console.log('done!'), 1500)` and you should see the results you expect.